# C++ Templates & C# Generics

Tags: c#, c++, .net

Has anyone tried mapping a C# generic to a C++ template? I am working on a 'round-about' way of accessing a 64-bit List in C# (by implementing it in a C++ dll), and am curious if there is anything special to feeding a C++ templated function a C# generic.

Comment: Forget C# for a minute; first how are you planning on exporting a C++ class template from a dll?

Comment: Templates are instantiated at compile-time, while generics are not. You won't be able to pass a generic type to a template directly, but might be able to use a base class. Also, for my curiosity, do you have a good reason for implementing the `List` in C++ or is it just academic?

Comment: @CoryNelson -> It's for a personal project of mine (Evolutionary Programming). I use zillions of nodes, and the program works faster if I can access them all while in RAM. Unfortunately, C# is kind of limited there, as the intelligentsia at Microsoft decided C# wasn't good enough for Lists with longs as indexes. I am not alone in my unhappiness here. Limiting myself to a Uint32 would be extremely annoying, and probably destroy performance.

Comment: @CoryNelson -> Anyway, I'm slowly porting the code to C++ (haven't used it in ages), and when I am done, I think I'll put it up on GitHub or something. I know tons of people are looking for a solution, and this one might work. I'm thinking of implementing long as an indexer at first, then ulong, then BigInteger. That should keep us free and clear of any stupidity for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, yes you can define managed ref classes in C++/CLI as templates and then access them from c#. The syntax to access them is the same as that of generics, but they are actually templates.

Template syntax for c++/CLI is described in wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI#Template_syntax